# PHP Symfony2 custom authentication without database (SOAP)

Tags: php, symfony

I have a soap to authenticate users

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://mysite/code/soap.wsdl');
$user   = $client->login('username','password');

if( isset($user['IdAccount']) && ($user['IdAccount'] > 0) )
   echo 'Logon OK';
else
   echo 'Logon Fail!';
```

I would like to use in Symfony2 without database, only in memory...

I tried to implement a [Custom UserProvider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html), but I do not have all the data needed to make it work...

```
class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $client = new SoapClient('http://mysite/code/soap.wsdl');

        $user   = $client->login($username, PASSWORD???? );

        if ( isset($user['IdAccount']) && ($user['IdAccount'] > 0) ) 
            return new WebserviceUser($username, PASSWORD????, SALT???, ROLES????);

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
    );
}
```

I can not change the soap

*sorry for my bad english! :(*

Comment: To do it the right way, you need you own custom Authentication Provider.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html. Not on easy thing to implement.  I found working through the tutorial backwards worked best.  But I'd strongly suggest looking for a SOAP authentication bundle.  I'm sure there are a couple of good ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to use form authentication and check password using SOAP service.

If you use Symfony 2.4 or above, you can use [SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html)

Example implementation:

```
// ... namespace and uses

class Authenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $soapClient;

    public function __construct(\SoapClient $soapClient)
    {
        $this->soapClient = $soapClient;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        $user = $this->soapClient->login($token->getUsername(), $token->getCredentials());
        if (isset($user['IdAccount']) && ($user['IdAccount'] > 0)) {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
            return new UsernamePasswordToken(
                $user,
                null,
                $providerKey,
                $user->getRoles()
            );
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken
            && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I do not understand how to implement `UserProviderInterface` for `$userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername())`

Comment: You can just skip that line and create user object (should implement `UserInterface`) from the SOAP method result. Or just create empty one (for example `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User`) with just username set. No need to use the UserProvider there.