# Symfony and SSO (Apache) - Authentification

Tags: php, single-sign-on, symfony

I have an authenticated user on the server via SSO. I can get it in my app with:

```
$user = $request->server->getHeaders();   
var_dump($user['X_REMOTE_USER']);
```

I have a SOAP web service to retrieve more informations about the user like his rights on the application.

I wanted to know what is the good way to securized my apps ?

eg: /admin if user got admin role

Must I authentificate my user on symfony ? If yes How can I identify my user on symfony ? (We don't want a Login Form)

I have seen that may be I can use a userProvider.But I don't how it works with a user who is already authentificated by the server.

Thanks for your help,
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can setting roles in security.yml file for ACL
Something like:

```
# security.yml
 security:
    access_control:
    # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

here is more info. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

But for authentication you need somethink like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984933/3758361, or you can try to use this bundle https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle

Comment: [Installing BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PZm4I.png


I am using a verion 3.0.3 of Symfony. So I can't  use BeSimpleSsoAAuthBundle.